# "Jump to definition" in Rust

Tags: rust

After years of coding in modern IDEs (Visual Studio, Xcode, JetBrain's products) I'm quite used to invaluable `Jump to definition` feature. It is especially invaluable for system libraries and frameworks when you yet learning the core features of the new language.

Is there any way to achieve the same functionality for the Rust combined with any modern IDE or text editor? Any vim, sublime text plugin?

Answer (score 2):

IDE support for Rust is not there yet. There exists at least the [Racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer) project, that provides a jump-to-definition feature among other things.

Racer is intended to be integrated into any IDE/text editor, and ships with an emacs integration.

Comment: FYI, the emacs key-binding for this is `M-.` (assuming you have Racer installed). I have been using this SO much since I learned it 30 minutes ago...

Answer (score 2):

In Vim and emacs you can use ctags to get you a lot of the way there; the language definitions are in `src/etc/ctags.rust` and you can produce tags for the Rust distribution with `make TAGS.vi` (or `make TAGS.emacs` for emacs’ format). See `mk/ctags.mk` for more information.

For setting them up and using them in Vim, see `:help tags`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called [rusty-tags](https://github.com/dan-t/rusty-tags) generating ctags for Rust. At the time of this post, it is still actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

The [RustDT](http://rustdt.github.io/) IDE now supports Open Definition functionality, using the [Racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer) tool.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime's [RustAutoComplete](https://github.com/glennw/RustAutoComplete) has a working Go to Definition using a separately installed [Racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer).
I'm using it and it works.

That being said, in 2014 the language is still in a flux and the Racer functionality is still limited.
I currenly have `"auto_complete": false` and only use the completion manually (with a keyboard shortcut) in order to avoid some Racer crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs can be integrated with [rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/) via [lsp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode). This will allow you to navigate the source code using Rust's type system. I describe a detailed setup in the code navigation section of my [Rust with Emacs guide](https://robert.kra.hn/posts/2021-02-07_rust-with-emacs/#code-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

[dumb-jump](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump) works well for rust.